# Load a CSV template and write data to it via java

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, supercsv, jsapar

I have a CSV template file, say, having 10 columns.
I would like to load this CSV file template, and then write data to the relevant cells(say only to 5 of the 10 cells) through a java program. 
I went through [JSAPAR](https://github.com/org-tigris-jsapar/jsapar), [SuperCSV](https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html) etc, but am not sure whether these libraries have the "stuff" what exactly I need.
Is there any framework supporting this kind of operations?

Comment: Can you see if apache velocity template is helpful for you. Plese see the link-  http://gognamunish.blogspot.in/2013/08/apache-velocity-template-to-generate.html

Comment: This is not work for any csv library. Use some lib to load your template into 2dim array, write your cells and save the array back using same lib.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is generally considered the best CSV toolkit for Java. It's a very lightweight library that makes working with CSV dead simple. I would recommend looking at it since it's not among the list of things you've tried yet.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I cross checked the OpenCSV framework and it looks good, but doesnt satisfy the "stuff" that I want to accomplish. None of these frameworks, handles loading csv files as templates(similar to loading excel template file and writing to it(Apache POI)). I was wondering is it because CSV is treated as a simple delimiter separated "text" stored in a single file.  I have no clues so far on how I can load the csv file as a template and then write to it..Seems it not possible.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Checkout freemarker: http://freemarker.org/

Open your text file. 
Enter freemarker paramerters for required cells.

Your template file may look something like below:

```
"Templatetext1","text2","text4", "${myVal4}",${myVal5}","text6", ${myVal7}",${myVal8}",${myVal9}","textInCell10"
```

Pass in the values, you have your csv from template.

If you want to pass for multiple rows you can use other elements like <#list> etc.